# javascript restart onchange event

Tags: javascript, jquery

```
<script>
function preview(input){    
    if(input.files && input.files[0]) {
    var reader = new FileReader();

    reader.onload = function(e){$('#previewImage').attr('src', e.target.result);}
    reader.readAsDataURL(input.files[0]);

    //1. detect image original width & height
    var imgWidth=$("#previewImage").width();
    var imgHeight=$("#previewImage").height();

    //2.run thumbnail class & get scale down's width and height         
    dimension= new thumbnail(imgWidth,imgHeight);
    var previewWidth=dimension.newWidth;    
    var previewHeight=dimension.newHeight;

    //3.chnage width & height for preview           
    $("#previewImage").width(previewWidth);
    $("#previewImage").height(previewHeight);

    $("#previewImage").show();
</script>


<input type='file' id="uploadImg" onchange="preview(this)" />
<img id="previewImage" />
```

I have an input type upload file, I use fileReader for preview before upload,
I have create a class to scale down the image's size for preview

it works perfect when user first time upload the image

but if user click upload again.
2nd image will use the previous width & height, is any way to restart onChange
so it won't use previous width & height

Comment: Can you create a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go: http://jsfiddle.net/L4zhd/5/

This way the thumbnail is always 50 pixels wide.  Just change `width="50"` to whatever you want.  Or replace it with height instead if you always want the height to be the same.